# Efficient Python programming

Tags: python, performance

I have a large, process-intensive function which returns tuple and I intend to split the tuple into 2 variables. I wish to know which is more efficient way of doing this? Let me illustrate:

My large function:

```
def calculate_equations(a, b, c):
    ...blah blah large, complex function...
    return x, y
```

**First method** of splitting the tuple (I need the 'if' statement as this function actually manipulates output of another function):

```
final_outcome = calculate_equations(a, b, c)
if final_outcome[0]: variable1 = final_outcome[0]
if final_outcome[1]: variable2 = final_outcome[1]
```

**Second method** of splitting the tuple (I need the 'if' statement as this function actually manipulates output of another function):

```
if calculate_equations(a, b, c)[0]: variable1 = calculate_equations(a, b, c)[0]
if calculate_equations(a, b, c)[1]: variable2 = calculate_equations(a, b, c)[1]
```

I actually prefer the second method as it seem more 'pythonic', but I'm not sure if it's more or less efficient that the first?

Comment: Possibly better posted to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The first method calls the expensive function only once. The second one calls it between 2 and 4 times.

Comment: in the second method, you are calling your function twice for one if condition.

Comment: Why do you need the if-statements again?

Comment: You're asking if the version that runs the same function 4 times is as efficient as the version that runs it once? At a guess, it's 4 times slower, but the only real answer is to measure and see. If that function is really your bottleneck though, I can't see any reason the second version _wouldn't_ be 4 times slower unless the function is already memoized.

Comment: You could even remove the `final_outcome` variable and just do `var, var2 = calculate_equations(a,b,c)`

Comment: *match* is correct.  Any other approach use if-statements is sure to be slower than tuple unpacking.  *Useless* is also correct, calling a slow function more than once is also sure to be slower than calling it once.   Lastly, if the function really is large and complex, then the argument passing and return value unpacking time are likely to be an insignificant part of the total running time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first method is a lot better, since it does not call the function repeatedly, which itself will likely take more time than storing the result into a variable. A more pythonic variant of the first would be:

```
final_outcome1, final_outcome2  = calculate_equations(a, b, c)
if final_outcome1: variable1 = final_outcome1
if final_outcome2: variable2 = final_outcome2
```

If your `final_outcome` variables are often truthy, I would even consider a variant using short-circuiting as a makeshift conditional assignment operator, which might be faster:

```
final_outcome1, final_outcome2  = calculate_equations(a, b, c)
variable1 = final_outcome1 or variable1
variable2 = final_outcome2 or variable2
```

Answer (score 0):

You could actually use `timeit` module or simply setup a print `time.time()` minus previous time to see the speed.
However, to cut things short, first method is going to be faster because second method involves recalculating by calling `calculate_equations` again for even 1 `if`.
Which means that your second method is going to call the same function 4 times in total potentially while the first method only calls it once.